# Errors with the gradle file and the Imports on my Project

Tags: android, gradle, import, dependencies

I am developing a project to parse data as JsonObject from the StarWars API (https://swapi.dev/api/). I am using a recyclerView to present the data in the View and some interfaces to have the relevant methods for the loading of data and handling of errors (with a client and server connection service). The project was working correctly, without errors until today where out of the blue I am getting several imports highlighted with red.

My gradle file is as follows:

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

```
android {
     compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.juangm.bottomnavigationmvp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
}

dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
 }
```

Errors as they appear in the BottomNavigationActivity class:

[Bottom Navigation Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9S7cj.jpg)

Any help is much appreciated. I tried to change some dependencies on my Gradle file, invalidate caches etch. but with no success. Maybe it is somehow related to the Android studio?

Answer (score 0):

Change buildToolsVersion to "27.0.3"

1. Clean build project
2. Invalidate cache / Restart Studio

If none of these above not work comment, please.